# Vungle video ad is not showing but audio is playing

Tags: android, ios, cocos2d-x, vundle, vungle-ads

I integrated vungle sdk for ios-mac .
When i requested to play an ad then audio of that ad
played but video did not play.

Anybody can answer the issue that why video of that ad is
not showing while audio of ad is still playing after calling the play ad.

Answer (score 0):

Issue is resolved just telling to my
viewController about the rootViewController
by adding self so it can understand what should
be display which is ad's video.